# lapply in return Shiny Module

Tags: r, shiny, module

I have the list of variables and some more stuffs. When I submit the information from the user, I used `lapply` to apply the module `updateServer`. Inside the module the user is able to edit the information, and it will save after the user click `update button`. The module return a dataframe.

How I can return the list of dataframes in the server after I call the Module?

**MODULE** *return dt*

```
# Module
updateUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        uiOutput(ns("title_out")),
        uiOutput(ns("x_label_out")),
        uiOutput(ns("y_label_out")),
        uiOutput(ns("sb_edit"))
    )
}
updateServer <- function(input, output, session, title_plot) {
    ns <- session$ns
    values <- reactiveValues(title = "",x_label = "", y_label = "")
    
    output$title_out <- renderUI({
        textInput(ns("title"), "Title", value = paste0("This is a title for ",title_plot))
    })
    
    
    output$x_label_out <- renderUI({
        textInput(ns("x_label"),"X Label", value = "")
    })
    
    
    output$y_label_out <- renderUI({
        textInput(ns("y_label"), "Y Label", value = "")
    })
    
    output$sb_edit <- renderUI({
        actionButton(ns("update"), "Update")
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$update,{
        values$title <- input$title 
        values$x_label <- input$x_label 
        values$y_label <- input$y_label 
    })
    
    dt <- reactive({
        dt <- data.frame(title = values$title, x_label = values$x_label, y_label = values$y_label)
    })
    
    return(list(dt = dt()))
}
```

**SERVER**

```
library(shiny)
# server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    var <- eventReactive(input$sb,{
        input$var 
    })
    
    handlers <- list()
    
    observe({
        handlers <<- lapply(var(), function(i){callModule(updateServer, paste0("test_",i), i) })
    })
    
    output$ui_out <- renderUI({
        lapply(var(), function(i){
            tagList(updateUI(paste0("test_",i)))
        })
    })
    
    
    # Return the list here
    output$out <- renderText({ ## 7
        req(length(handlers) > 0)
        out <- lapply(handlers, function(h) h$dt())
    }) 
})
```

**UI**

```
# ui

library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            tagList(
            selectInput("var", "Variables for Plot",choices = names(mtcars), selected = names(mtcars)[1:3], multiple = T),
            actionButton("sb", "Submit")
            )
        ),

        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("ui_out"),
            verbatimTextOutput("out")
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without a minimal reproducible example

Comment: It supposed return ```update$dt```in server below # Return the list here

Comment: I just updated the codes @MattCowgill